# Unable to bind data from async method to a listview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding

I'm new to UWP and C# in general. I'm trying to browse files from my video library and bing the data to a listview control. Everything is running fine, I've cheched all the variables and they do content the right information, however nothing is populated on the list view. Could you give me a hint on how to make it work ? Thank you and sorry in advance if my code is not the state of art, i'm learning ;)

here is my main class :

```cs
namespace RedMedia
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private readonly List<Video> Videos;
        public string resultat;
        int i;
        public MainPage()
        {  
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Videos = new List<Video>();
            InitVideos();
        }

        private async void  InitVideos()
        {
            var files = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView, 50, ThumbnailOptions.ReturnOnlyIfCached);
                    Video video = new Video();
                    video.Title = file.Name;
                    if (thumbnail != null)
                    {
                        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(thumbnail, randomAccessStream);
                        randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
                        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
                                video.Cover = bitmapImage;
                    }

                    Videos.Add(video);
               }
```

here is my class video :

```cs
namespace RedMedia.Modeles
    {
        class Video : 
        {
            public BitmapImage Cover { get; set; }
            public uint Bitrate { get; set; }
            public List<string> Directors { get; set; }
            public List<string> Producers { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
            public uint Height { get; set; }
            public List<string> Keywords { get; set; }
            public uint Rating { get; set; }
            public string Subtitle { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Publisher { get; set; }
            public uint Year { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public string category { get; set; }

            public Video()
            {
                //some code to do
            }
        }

    }
```

and finally my main.xaml

```xml
    <Page
        x:Class="RedMedia.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Data="using:RedMedia.Modeles"
        mc:Ignorable="d" >

        <Page.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Data:Video" x:Key="VideoDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Page.Resources>

        <Grid Background="Orange" Margin="0,20,20,0">
            <ListView  Name="lstview1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Videos}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VideoDataTemplate}">
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

    </Page>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make all your classes public.
Then, next step, your Videos collection/list should be defined and implemented like it follows:

```
public List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
```

NOTE: In order to follow MVVM or whatever pattern you use, I would suggest to restructure your code, so that you use bindings to your view model, not to code-behind.
In that case, you can also implement INotifyPropertyChanged and use it when defining your VM properties.
Then your VM property would look like this:

```
private List<Video> _videos = new List<Video>();

public List<Video> Videos 
{
   get { return _videos; }
   set 
   {
      _videos = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Maybe this link could be helpful if you decide to go with it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/

Comment: I'd use ObservableCollection in this case rather than List as it implements INotifyCollectionChanged